# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Model' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces

I want to use Model functions in view

My controller function code:

```
 $model = Tickets::find(1);
 View::make('view')->withModel($model);

 return view('index.search', ['tickets' => $result]);
```

My model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tickets extends Model
{
    public function someFunction() {
        echo 'hello world!';
    }
}
```

My view code:

```
{{ $model->someFunction() }}
```

Comment: import `App\Model`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import your model like this:

```
use App\Tickets;
```

right after line with namespace so it should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tickets;
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work (
still writes that such a class does not exist

Comment: @Ostap34PHP Well, but I assume you don't have Model class existing. Shouldn't you use `Ticket` class instead? Please look at edited answer

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the issue:

```php
use App\Models\Ticket;
```

For laravel 7:

```php
use App\Tickets;
```

For laravel 8:

```php
use App\Models\Ticket;
```

Comment: You have just copied the accepted answer without formatting the code.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work you will either have to use the full namespace:

```
$model = \App\Tickets::find(1);
```

---

Or add a `use` statement to the top of the controller:

```
use App\Tickets;
```

and load the model with:

```
$model = Tickets::find(1);
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work (
still writes that such a class does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tickets extends Model
{
    public function someFunction() {
        echo 'hello world!';
    }
}
```

And controller function should be

```
$model = Tickets::find(1);
 View::make('view')->withModel($model);

 return view('index.search', ['tickets' => $result]);
```

Comment: as I was told from the previous answers, one has to add to the model:
`use app\tickets;`

Comment: Actually you don't have to add use `app\tickets;` to Model, you have to add it to controller. When you extends class Tickets to Model, it automatically gets the model. Secondly, you are writing plural in Class, its not good practice. Also first letter of Class name should be capital